# C++, Looks like wrong constructor being called (const reference parameter)

Tags: c++, constructor

My program is not compiling with the error

> MenuModel::MenuModel(const MenuModel &): cannot convert argument 1 from MenuController *const to const MenuModel &

I am calling the constructor with the `this` of a `MenuController` class, which is a `MenuController *` as expected, but the constructor, even though its declared to take a MenuController pointer, expects a reference of itself.

Here is the code from my classes

```
AbstractModel::AbstractModel(AbstractController * controller) {
    std::cout << "AbstractModel constructor called" << std::endl;
    this->controller = controller;
    objects = new GameObject*[GAME_HEIGHT * GAME_WIDTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < GAME_HEIGHT * GAME_WIDTH; i++) {
        objects[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

MenuModel::MenuModel(MenuController * menuController) : AbstractModel(menuController) {
}

MenuController::MenuController() {
    model = new MenuModel(this);
}
```

I tried making the constructor take a const pointer instead as that's what the error message said it was passing, and maybe the `MenuModel` class was defaulting to the copy constructor, but that didn't work.

Anyone have any idea on why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is `model` pointer type?  If not, try `model = MenuModel(this);`

Comment: yea, model is declared as AbstractModel* model;

Comment: OT, but instead of your nullptr loop you can do `new GameObject*[x]();`   (Using a vector would be even better though)

Comment: Hope you tried this : `MenuModel::MenuModel(const MenuController * const menuController)`

Comment: What compiler are you using? GCC 6.3 compiles this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55d99f14294df0ed GCC 4.3.2 also does well http://ideone.com/MKPXEh

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to check,  but it's the one that comes bundled by default to visual studio 2017, and (const MenuController * const menuController) unfortunately did not work either. Would it help if I posted the contents of all the relevant files? seems like the simplified version should compile but probably something else is happening

Comment: @user1971354 Does your VS2017 compile this http://ideone.com/MKPXEh ? If yes, then the problem is in another place, not where you described in this post. If not, then it looks like a bug in VS2017 compiler.